# Integration of Bernoullis equation for velocity potential in fluids

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics

I'm supposed to find the equations and boundary conditions for the velocity potential. The only things which I have given are that we have a stream of depth h, which flows at a constant speed U in the direction of x.

A hint was given with: pay particular attention to the choice of the value of the integration constant in Bernoulli’s equation

Therefore I'm pretty sure that I'm supposed to integrate Bernoulli's equation:

${\phi}_{t}+\frac{1}{2}|\nabla\phi|^2 +\frac{p}{\rho}+ gz= f(t)$

Honestly, I don't even know where to start. I'm not sure if I should treat it as a differential equation and if yes how.

Comment: First write out the equation for your specific setup (i.e. depth $h$, speed $U$) and work from there. Does your system depend on time? If not you can remove the $\phi_t$ term and let $f(t)$ be a constant.

Comment: Hi, thank you for fast your response. I'm missing a lot of prior information so therefore I don't know how the equation should look like. I know that $U = \nabla \phi$ and that it should not depend on time. If I can remove therefore $\phi{t}$, does the equation then just look like $\phi = \int \sqrt{2*(f-\frac{p}{\rho}-g*z)}$ and then integration in x,y,z direction?